# How execute a pipeline in bash using a python wrapper?

Tags: bash, python-2.7

**Scenario:**

I have a pipeline in a bash script and a list of some process along with their arguments. I want to run a python script after the execution of each process (executable) in the pipeline if the process is in my list.
(I use Python 2.7)

**My proposed solution:**

Using a python wrapper script. I have replaced all executable in the pipeline with my custom python script which:

1) checks the process if is in the list then FLAG=True

2) execute the process by the original executable using `subprocess.Popen(process.command, shell=True).communicate()`

3) if FLAG==True then do something.

**Problem:**

Using the current solution when I run the process using 
`subprocess.Popen().communicate()`, the processes will execute separately
and they cannot get the output of inner process (child process) to the outer process (parent).

For example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

Mean=`P1  $Image1 -M`
P2 "$Image2"  $Mean -F
```

We have not output value of Mean in the second line execution.
Second line will execute like:

```sh
subprocess.Popen("P2 $Image2  \nP1  $Image1 -M -F" , shell=True).communicate()
```

Therefore, it returns an error!

Is there a better way in python to execute process like this?

Please let me know if there is any other suggestion for this scenario (I'm a very beginner in bash).

Comment: Why use a shell at all? Much better to run two separate processes, one invoking `['P1', image1, '-M']` and the other invoking `['P2', image2, str(mean), '-F']`, both with the default `shell=False`; that way none of your filenames or arguments can try to be interpreted as code meaningful to the shell. (Otherwise, think about what happens if someone gives you an image with `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` in its name!)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use bash at all.

Assuming modern Python 3.x:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

image1 = sys.argv[1]
image2 = sys.argv[2]

p1 = subprocess.run(['P1', image1, '-M'], check=True, capture_output=True)
p2 = subprocess.run(['P2', image2, p1.stdout.strip(), '-F'], check=True, capture_output=True)
print(p2_result.stdout)
```

See here that we refer to `p1.stdout.strip()` where we need the mean value in `p2`'s arguments.

Comment: This two commands was just an example of the whole pipeline, so, I already have not `p1_result.stdout.strip()`. I just run line by line and expect there be an interactive connection between outputs of child process and parents.

Comment: My application works correctly by `subprocess.Popen().communicate()` untill there is a command with embeded another command like the example.

Comment: An *interactive* connection? Your original bash script wouldn't do that at all; it purely waited for P1 to exit before starting P2, just like the Python code here does.